# How do you install external python libraries in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have been using VS Code for a few months for coding in python 3.7.2 for both my school and personal projects. But I am stuck at a stage when I tried to code a discord bot in python. I used pip to install the discord library last night but for some reason when I `import discord`, it throws an error:

```
File "c:/Users/Jyotirmay Kumar Jha/VS Code Projects/discord/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import discord
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'
```

I have installed python in the directory "C:\Python\Python37\python.exe" but I am really not sure if the discord module got installed in that location because that is the python interpreter that VS Code is using.

[image]

So, I tried browsing the web to find the actual method to install a module that can be used by VS Code too but they all suggested that I use windows command prompt for it which I had actually done.

What I want to ask is how to get that discord module to work in Visual Studio Code too? And for future, how do I know if a module is installed on my device?

Comment: open terminal there using ctrl+` and then execute pip install discord.py and it wil lwork (check if youre using the correct python path from that menu)

Comment: @TGHimanshu yea i just tried that and luckily it worked. i was about to post a comment about this. but thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to use something along the lines of `python3 -m pip install discord.py` as python3 uses a separate pip version. Looking at https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/228, it seems there's also a dead/not real package under the same name that doesn't work.

Comment: the command actually worked but the module was not made available to VS Code. Ran the command in the VS Code terminal and it worked. Thanks for the suggestion tho.