# How can I add the Discord module in python without using pip?

Tags: python, module, pip, discord, discord.py

How are you guys?

So to get straight to the point I wanted to create a Discord bot using Python but the thing is that when I want to install the discord module using pip by typing `pip install discord` but since I'm using a PC without admin rights I have an error saying that it can't launch this program (pip)

So I'm here to ask if anyone knows how can I install the Discord module in python without pip ?

Thanks in advance!

~Sami

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which IDE you are using
For example, you can download pycharm if you don't already have it and you can download the package from pycharm itself.

How you can do that is going to file ➜ Settings ➜ Project ➜ Python Interpreter ➜ and click the + sign over the package label and there you will be able to search for any package you want like discord.py

Comment: Hi, so I'm using VS Code as an IDE so if you can tell me how to install the Discord package in it that would be great!

Comment: Go to this question it has a answer for your problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65228199/how-do-you-install-external-python-libraries-in-vs-code

Comment: No sorry it didn't help me, because the guy says that he needs to install the module using pip but I can't use pip since as I said the program needs admin rights but this PC doesn't have admin rights to launch pip

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py and download it as a zip (`Code` -> `Download ZIP`)

[image]

2. Extract the zip file on your desktop
3. Open the command propmt and CD into the `discord.py-master` directory (with `cd Desktop\discord.py-master`
4. Run `python setup.py install`

Comment: Hi, so the problem is as I said this PC doesn't have the admin rights so if I try to execute the following command: `python3 setup.py install` I have an error saying that the system cannot execute the specified program :/

Comment: Try using `pip install --user discord.py`

Comment: Same problem, it's saying that the system can't execute it, it really sucks :|

Comment: Do you have any other solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
py -m pip install discord
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this**

set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python34\Scripts

check this link for more ['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

**If the above doesn't work**

You have to download the discord.py module here.
https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/#files

and read this if you don't know how to import files

[How do I use an external .py file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980059/how-do-i-use-an-external-py-file)

**else**

reinstall python and set the path like the below image

https://miro.medium.com/max/1282/1*ecMIFT0gDLcLRD1y5q8_Tg.png